# 15 GB of unaccounted-for space in filesystem

Tags: disk-usage, ext4

```
[nathanb /mnt/work] sudo du -hs .
23G .
[nathanb /mnt/work] df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        40G   38G  6.4M 100% /mnt/work
```

Where is the other 15 GB?

```
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt/work type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Updating to respond to comments

```
[nathanb /mnt/work] sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1
tune2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Last mounted on:          /mnt/work
Inode count:              2621440
Block count:              10485752
Reserved block count:     524287
Free blocks:              3955615
Free inodes:              2522921
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
```

And

```
[nathanb /mnt/work] df -i .
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1      2621440 29764 2591676    2% /mnt/work
```

And

```
[nathanb /mnt/work] sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Warning!  /dev/sdb1 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
/dev/sdb1: clean, 98519/2621440 files, 6530137/10485752 blocks
```

And

```
[nathanb /mnt/work] sudo lsof | grep deleted
[nathanb /mnt/work]
```

There are no mount points below /mnt/work

```
[nathanb /mnt/work] grep /mnt/work /proc/self/mountinfo
22 19 8:17 / /mnt/work rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime - ext4 /dev/sdb1 rw,data=ordered
```

Well, of all the things...seems to be working again. And just like I have no idea what caused the problem, I have no idea what fixed it.

```
[nathanb /mnt/work] df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1        40G   22G   16G  59% /mnt/work
```

I had unmounted a couple of the NFS clients hitting up the volume in preparation for umounting and fscking it, but I hadn't unmounted all of them...and I checked right after the unmount and the space hadn't gone down. But then I got back from doing some other work and noticed it was unwedged.

Annoying and unfulfilling...wish I knew what the problem had been so I could award some points to some folks...thanks for all the help, though, and if it happens again I'll try to get more forensics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this data that keeps reappearing after partition delete + new partition creation?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181482/what-is-this-data-that-keeps-reappearing-after-partition-delete-new-partition)

Comment: @jordanm 40% reserved space seems very unlikely. In the duplicate, it's only 1-2%.

Comment: @jordanm No, not a dup. Math suggests 2.1GB of the space is reserved.

Comment: If it's not deleted files, then it could be a lost file, which would be detected by `fsck`.

Comment: @Barmar I ran fsck -n because I can't umount this fs right now, and it said it was clean. After folks are done using the mount I'll umount it and do a full fsck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the filesystem was exported via NFS, there’s a fair chance that the discrepancy was due to deleted files... If files are deleted while open on NFS clients, `lsof` on the server won’t see them because there is no `/proc/.../fd` entry corresponding to them; but they will still occupy disk space as seen by `df`.

Diagnosing this requires running `lsof` with the `-N` option on every client.

(This doesn’t explain the delay you saw in recovering the space after unmounting the volume from the clients, but it’s the best explanation I can think of for the rest of the symptoms.)

Answer (score 0):

`fuser -k -M -m /mnt/work` should heel. Warning! it just literally kills processes accessing /mnt/work. Include `-TERM` to request termination.

The culprit is deleted files that are held open, which du can't see but df could.

For e.g.

```
$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       209M   66M  128M  35% /boot
$ sudo du -sh .
64M     .
$  sudo fallocate -l 100M tmp_file
$ ls -lh tmp_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100M Feb  3 02:24 tmp_file
$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       209M  166M   28M  86% /boot
$ sudo du -sh .
164M    .
$ exec 20<tmp_file
$ sudo rm tmp_file
$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       209M  166M   28M  86% /boot
$ sudo du -sh .
64M     .
```

The tmp_file is still open. If it's closed 'df' can see free.

```
$ exec 20<&-
$ df -h .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       209M   66M  128M  35% /boot
```

Comment: I don't see any deleted files with active file handles in lsof output, as mentioned in the comments above.

Comment: You didn't sudo. Or are you root. No $/# ?

Comment: I re-ran with sudo just to verify and got the same results. Updated the post